# Promise { <pending> } in Web3

Tags: javascript, web3js

I need something help.. I'm trying to make an async request but the response is a `Promise { <pending> }`

This is my code

```
const getBalance = async (adress) => {
  try {
    let wei = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};

let balanceWallet = getBalance(address);
console.log(balanceWallet);
```

So when I run my code to debug it returns `Promise { <pending> }` I don't know what's wrong in my code

Comment: Put `console.log(wei)` *inside* the async function, after you have `await`ed the promise. Or call `const balanceWallet = await getBalance(address);` inside of another `async` function (or use `getBalance(address).then(balanceWallet => …)`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**getBalance** is an async function :) JS does not allow us to use async/await on the program top level but we can use then/catch to get promise result)

You just have to use (but before u have to change getBalance function and return promise there)

```
const getBalance = (adress) => web3.eth.getBalance(address);

getBalance(address)
.then(balanceWallet => {
  console.log(balanceWallet)
  // some logic with result
})
.catch(error => /** handle an error **/ )
```

I hope it helps! Enjoy programming!

Comment: Ok, I got it. But my interest is to save the value to use it later. For example for use the method fromWei()

Comment: I update my example, please look at this)